# How to call random function from list of functions?

Tags: python

```
t = 1
while t < total:
    random.choice([xs_tables(t), medium_tables(t), large_tables(t), xl_tables(t)])
    t = t + total
```

Above I"m trying to call a random function from a list of 4 functions that will take `t` as a input.  Right now the code is calling each function in the list instead of just one random function.  I think it might have something to do with the (`t`) but I'm not sure how else to pass the functions `t`.

Comment: `random.choice([xs_tables, medium_tables, large_tables, xl_tables])(t)` Note that the function call has been moved out of the random selection

Comment: What's `total`, some global variable? Hope the functions change it, because otherwise what you have is an infinite loop...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
random.choice([xs_tables, medium_tables, large_tables, xl_tables])(t)
```

This way, you *first* select the function and *then* call it with the argument `t`.